# Why File is not deleting in C Language

Tags: c, strtok

Hello I am new in c and ı have homework about tcp program and one poin in this project I cant pass can anywone help me please

**StartsWithDEL()** this function  catch **DEL user.txt** like return true
**trim()** like trim and give only file name user.txt

BUT when I write client line DEL user.txt  is not going delete

```
      if (StartsWithDEL(line,"DEL") == 1)
            {
                 char *deltoken = strtok(line, "DEL");
                 char *itemDeleting = trim(deltoken);
//in this section I cach file name but cant delete it 
                    remove(itemDeleting);
                    send(client, "\n" ,strlen("\n"),0);
    
             }
```

[image]

Comment: `strtok` doesn't work the way you seem to think it works. Read the documentation. Do a little experimenting, printing the result after calling `strtok`.

Comment: We can't debug incomplete code snippets. Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If `remove` fails, it will set `errno` to tell you why.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `strtok()` in incorrect.  The second argument is a string or allowed token delimiters, which in your case a .  If you call it with `"DEL"`, it will overwrite the `D` with `\0` and `deltoken` will point to that empty string.

If you choose to use `strtok()` then:

```
char* token = strtok( line, " " ) ;

if( strcmp( token, "DEL" ) == 0 )
{
    char* itemDeleting = strtok( NULL, " " ) ;
    remove(itemDeleting);
    send(client, "\n" ,strlen("\n"),0);
}
```

However if is simpler to avoid the complexity of `strtok()`, and the fact that it modifies `line` by inserting nuls makes it undesirable in many cases.  The code above also won't work if a filename may contains spaces.

There are many alternative solutions, for example:

```
size_t delimiter_index = strcspn( line, " " ) ;

if( strncmp( line, "DEL", delimiter_index ) == 0 )
{
    char* itemDeleting = &line[delimiter_index] ;
    while( *itemDeleting == 0 && *itemDeleting != '\0' ) itemDeleting++ ;

    remove(itemDeleting);
    send(client, "\n" ,strlen("\n"),0);
}
```

Since I have no idea what `StartsWithDEL()` or `trim()` so I have avoided them.